# how to cast const vector to non-const

Tags: c++, googletest

I am doing a gtest. The function I would like to test takes two parameters.

```
int functionA(const ObjectA& obja, const stl::vector<ObjectB>& objb)
```

In my gtest, I would like to mock some test cases.

For `obja`, what I did is:

```
ObjectA* obja = new ObjectA();
obja->type() = someValue; //setter function
obja->value() = someValue; // setter too
```

and then pass `*(const_cast<ObjectA*>(obja))` as the parameter.

But for the vector, I am not sure what `const` defines. I tried:

```
stl::vector<ObjectB*>*  input;
ObjectB objb = new ObjectB();
objb->type() = someValue // setter
objb->id() = someValue//setter
input.push_back(objb);
```

then pass `*(const_cast<ObjectB*>(input))` as the parameter.

But I get an error message saying "no matching function".

Could anyone tell me how I can mock `input` and pass it in gtest?

For your convenience, the code in gtest is (assume class name is A):

```
ObjectA* obja = new ObjectA();
obja->type() = someValue; //setter function
obja->value() = someValue; // setter too

stl::vector<ObjectB*>*  input;
ObjectB objb = new ObjectB();
objb->type() = someValue // setter
objb->id() = someValue//setter
input.push_back(objb);

A* instanceA = A::getInstance();
EXPECT_EQ(-2, instanceA->functionA(*(const_cast<ObjectA*>(obja)),*(const_cast<ObjectB*>(input)))) ;
```

I also tried not using `const_cast` and pointers, I tried:

```
const ObjectA a;
a.type() = somevalue;
a.value() = somevalue;

const stl::vector<ObjectB> input;
ObjectB objb;
objb.type() = some;
input.push_back(objb);
```

and just pass `input` and `a` as parameters in test.

but I get an error saying "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" on `a.type() = somevalue;`

I think it is because there are two `type()` in class `ObjectA`, one is a setter without `const`, one is a getter with `const`. If I declare `a` as `const`, it believes `type()` is the getter rather than the setter, so it cannot be a left-side value. That's why I want to use `const_cast`.

Comment: Why does your test code use pointers at all? You'd save yourself a lot of trouble if you just stuck to automatic storage duration, just like the code you are calling

Comment: And the problem is not because of `const` , it's because your `input` vector is storing pointers while the function expects a vector that stores complete objects

Comment: Don't cast away const.  You can't know if the object passed to the function was `const` or not.

Comment: There are so many compiler errors in the posted code that it's hard to answer the question. Please fix the errors.

Comment: @Coolboy, it because you suddently decided to declare `a` as const. You are making life difficult, try without pointers, without const_cast and and without declaring `a` as const.

Comment: You've clearly got the idea that because the function declaration uses `const` you have to use `const` or `const_cast` in your code. That idea is wrong. All the function declaration is saying is that the objects passed to it **can** be const, not that they **have** to be const.

Comment: @Coolboy It's an out of bounds access on your vector. I.e. you're trying to access an element of your vector that doesn't not exist.

Comment: @Coolboy That is a new issue not related to this question. It needs to be posted as a separate question of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `const`, that's not the issue, The problem is the unnecessary and sometimes incorrect use of pointers.

Look at the declaration of the function you are testing.

```
int functionA(const ObjectA& obja, const stl::vector<ObjectB>& objb)
```

No pointers there. Now look at the declaration of the vector you are trying to pass to the function.

```
stl::vector<ObjectB*>*  input;
```

That's (a pointer to) a vector of pointers, that's why the code doesn't work. The test function vector is not a vector of pointers. Here's how to write the code *without any pointers*.

```
ObjectA obja;
obja.type() = someValue; //setter function
obja.value() = someValue; // setter too

stl::vector<ObjectB> input;
ObjectB objb;
objb.type() = someValue // setter
objb.id() = someValue//setter
input.push_back(objb);

A* instanceA = A::getInstance();
EXPECT_EQ(-2, instanceA->functionA(obja, input));
```

Much easier.

Comment: @Coolboy Yes and see comments above, its because you have declared `obja` as const which you should not have done.

Comment: there should be a canonical "How to fix my problem with pointers?" - "Don't use pointers." :P

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `const_cast` is completely unnecessary and can be removed.  For one thing, you are casting non-const to non-const, which is redundant. But also, a non-const object can be directly assigned to a `const` reference of matching type, so you don't need the casts anway.  But, in the case of `input`, you are not even casting it to a compatible type, so you should have gotten a compiler error on that cas.

More importantly, you are not allocating an actual `stl::vector` object for `input` to point at, so you have **undefined behavior** when you try to dereference `input`.

Try this instead:

```
ObjectA *obja = new ObjectA();
obja->type() = someValue; //setter function
obja->value() = someValue; // setter too

stl::vector<ObjectB*> *input = new stl::vector<ObjectB*>();
ObjectB objb = new ObjectB();
objb->type() = someValue // setter
objb->id() = someValue//setter
input->push_back(objb);

A *instanceA = A::getInstance();
EXPECT_EQ(-2, instanceA->functionA(*obja, *input))
```

Which can be simplified if you get rid of all your uses of `new`:

```
ObjectA obja;
obja.type() = someValue; //setter function
obja.value() = someValue; // setter too

stl::vector<ObjectB*> input;
ObjectB objb;
objb.type() = someValue // setter
objb.id() = someValue//setter
input.push_back(&objb);

A *instanceA = A::getInstance();
EXPECT_EQ(-2, instanceA->functionA(obja, input))
```

Comment: It does in YOUR code, but not in MY code.  I don't declare `a` as `const`, but you are.  Don't do that, it is wrong in this situation.  You can't modify a `const` object, that is the whole point of `const`. Did you even TRY the code I gave you before you decided to change it?

Comment: @Coolboy well, that would be related to the implementation of `functionA()`, which is not related to this question. That needs to be posted as a separate question of its own.